# Combination of named vectors

Tags: r, vector

I have named vectors which I'd like to combine as follows:

```
v1 <- c(0,1,2,3)
v2 <- c(0,1,2,3)
v3 <- c(0,1,2,3)
names(v1) <- c("This","is","an","example")
names(v2) <- c("This","great","value","random")
names(v3) <- c("This","This","and","This")
```

expected result for v1 and v2:

```
This is an example great value random
0    1  2  3       1     2     3
```

and for v1 and v3:

```
This is an example This and This
0    1  2  3       1    2   3
```

As you can see, the vectors are just bound together if names differ. If there would be several occurances of the name in the resulting vector, it is kept once if the corresponding value is the same, but multiple times if values differ from each occurence. 
I don't know if I made clear what I'd like to achieve.

Is the a way to achieve something like this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make a helper function, like this:

```
Combiner <- function(vec1, vec2, vecOut = TRUE) {
  temp <- unique(rbind(data.frame(as.table(vec1)),
                       data.frame(as.table(vec2))))
  if (isTRUE(vecOut)) setNames(temp$Freq, temp$Var1)
  else temp
}
```

The point is to compare both the names and the values, and I found it easiest to just put that into the form of a `data.frame`.

Usage would then be:

```
Combiner(v1, v2)
#    This      is      an example   great   value  random 
#       0       1       2       3       1       2       3 
Combiner(v1, v3)
#    This      is      an example    This     and    This 
#       0       1       2       3       1       2       3
```

---

For any number of vectors, you can modify the function to be something like:

```
Combiner <- function(..., vecOut = TRUE) {
  dots <- list(...)
  if (any(is.null(sapply(dots, names)))) stop("All vectors must be named")
  temp <- unique(do.call(rbind, lapply(dots, function(x) {
    data.frame(Name = names(x), Value = unname(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  })))
  if (isTRUE(vecOut)) setNames(temp$Value, temp$Name)
  else temp
}
```

While the first version will only work with numeric named vectors (since it makes use of `as.table`), the second version should also work with named character vectors.

Comment: Okay it works with the example data - so far so good. On my real data, which is generated all the same but of type character instead of numeric, I get the following error: `Error in unique(rbind(data.frame(as.table(vec1)), data.frame(as.table(vec2)))) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'unique': Error in as.table.default(vec2) : cannot coerce to a table`

Comment: @MineSweeper, not sure. I've just updated the "Combiner" function at the end of the post to not use `table`. Can you try that version?

Comment: Works flawless with the second version (I have to remove the `isTRUE`) thank you ;)